# Insert more claim into identity OnTokenValidated event of JWT Bearer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, json-web-token

Currently, I'm making a SPA using angular 4 & net core 1.1 . My system uses JWT for checking user identity. Everytime user accesses into my system, I want to check his/her identity (status, role) in database and update to HttpContext.Identity.

Here is my code:

```
OnTokenValidated = async context =>
{
    // Find unit of work.
    var unitOfWork = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
    var identityService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IIdentityService>();

    // Find claim identity attached to principal.
    var claimIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Ticket.Principal.Identity;

    // Find email from claims list.
    var email =
        claimIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email))
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    // Email is invalid.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        return;

    // Find account information.
    var condition = new SearchAccountViewModel();
    condition.Email = new TextSearch();
    condition.Email.Value = email;
    condition.Email.Mode = TextComparision.Equal;

    // Find accounts based on conditions.
    var accounts = unitOfWork.RepositoryAccounts.Search();
    accounts = unitOfWork.RepositoryAccounts.Search(accounts, condition);

    // Find the first matched account in the system.
    var account = await accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // Account is not found.
    if (account == null)
        return;

    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) identityService.InitiateIdentity(account);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Enum.GetName(typeof(Roles), account.Role)));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, Enum.GetName(typeof(Statuses), account.Status)));

    context.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
}
```

In my **AccountController.cs** I have a function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Find personal profile.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("personal-profile")]
public IActionResult FindProfile()
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) Request.HttpContext.User.Identity;
    var claims = identity.Claims.ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Value);
    return Ok(claims);
}
```

Here is the result I have:

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "linhndse03150@gmail.com.vn",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "Goldarina Wharrier",
  "auth_time": "1494072536661.38",
  "nbf": "1494043736",
  "exp": "1494047336",
  "iss": "iConfess Ordinary",
  "aud": "http://localhost:5001"
}
```

No role or status had been included into identity.
My question is:
- How can I add more claims into request identity after validating token and searching user information in database.

Could anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Comment: So if I understood correctly.. you are calling an api to return claims? Why are you not retrieving the claims from the jwt on the client?

Comment: What happen if the user is not allowed to system anymore. For example, yesterday I gave you a token to access into my system, but today, I change your account status to Disabled to block your access. My purpose is to validate the token and update it with some more claims from database.

Comment: Shorten your token lifespan!

Comment: What if the account status is changed to Disabled within token lifetime. For example: My token lives in 5 minutes, but account status is changed to disabled at minute 3.  Basically, I think 60 mins is a suitable time for a token lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
context.Principal.AddIdentity(identity);
```

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/59139000/3936440 has some more information about this approach.