# access_token / id_token doesn't have Role information, possible to add additional information into the token instead of checking on every page?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a React project with API (net core). My website menus/fields will be shown/hidden based on the `Role` of the user. The user will login to my website via external oidc.

However, the `access_token` and `id_token` coming from the oidc doesn't have the `Role` information, it will only have their `email`, which I will use to check against my Database to determine which `Role` is the logged in user. Currently I have an API to get `Role` based on their `access_token`, so it's something like

```
public string getRoles(string access_token)
{
    //check Database
    return role;
}
```

This function will be called in almost every page so I was wondering is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What I think the ideal solution about your scenario is adding the user role claim to the access token and we can use  attribute liken `[Authorize(Roles = "Watever")]` to validate the role, so can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892911/14574199) help you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the claim to the HttpContext.User when the signin is confirmed with the role from the DB. When you define this connection in your startup, be sure to handle the OnTokenValidated event.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            var claim = new Claim("Role", "TheirRole");

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { claim });

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(identity);

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can access this within the controller (or anywhere with HttpContext) like so

```
var claim = HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Role == "TheirRole");
```

Comment: This is what I currently do, onTokenValidated is actually being called over and over. So I was wondering if there's a better solution.